# Exception in thread django-main-thread with urls.py file

Tags: python, windows-10, django-urls, python-3.9

I got problem with Django urls.py file. When i write `python manage.py runserver` this error pops out:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\python\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "D:\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\TestDjango\test_project\test_project\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from test_project.test_app.views import main_view
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_project.test_app'
```

It happens only to **new projects** (projects downloaded from GitHub work just fine) and only after adding path in urls.py. I've looked at many django-main-threads on this site, but none helped me.

**urls.py**

```
from test_project.test_app.views import main_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', main_view())
]
```

**If i write `from test_app.views import main_view` it shows error "Unresolved reference 'test_app'".**

**settings.py INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test_app'
]
```

**views.py**

```
def main_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Why won't you work?")
```

**Windows 10, Python 3.9, Django 3.1.4**

Comment: To add an app did you try the command `python manage.py startapp test_app`?

Comment: Yes i used this command